# Greasemonkey script that programmatically presses a Sencha Touch button

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script that automates a task on a website. I need to fill a form and then press a button as I was doing it by hand. So far, I'm not able to press the button, no matter what I try.
This is the button code:

```
<a class="x-button-normal x-button x-iconalign-left x-layout-box-item Recruit x-last x-      button-pressed" id="ext-button-8" style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;">
<span class="x-badge" style="display: none;"></span>
<span class="x-button-icon" style="background-image: url(https://d38957szc5yx03.cloudfront.net/s/r/mH8qUaabmHUogiiMhHvU1A.png);" id="ext-element-53"></span>
<span class="x-button-label" id="ext-element-52">Recruit</span>
</a>
```

and these are some of the things I tried, without success:

```
$('ext-button-8').trigger('click');
$('ext-button-8').trigger('tap');
document.getElementById('#ext-button-8').click();
Ext.query('#ext-button-8').dom.click();
Ext.get('ext-button-8').dom.click();
```

At this point, either I'm completely missing something or I need to trigger a different event to activate the button.

Comment: Just a typo from copy-paste, I did that the right way, I'll edit the mistake in the post.

Comment: Did you try var btn = Ext.Viewport.down('.button[id=ext-button-8]'); btn.fireEvent('tap', btn);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the whole problem was that the button does not react to a 'click' event but to a 'tap' one. The following code works:

```
Ext.get('ext-button-8').fireEvent('tap');
```

It probably can be done in plain Javascript too but firing a touch event is a bit more complicated that way.